# Using column numbers for dependent variables in regression functions

Tags: r

I'm stuck with this programming problem.

I want to create a regression tree for seven of the columns in the `algae` dataframe, from 12 to 18, but I want to use a loop to avoid doing the same thing seven times by hand. I have the following code:

```
library(DMwR)
data(algae)
algae<-algae[-manyNAs(algae),]
algae<-knnImputation(algae,k=10,meth="weighAvg")

library(rpart)

algae.rpart<-list()
for(i in 1:7){
  algae.rpart[[i]]<-rpart(algae[i+11]~.,data=algae)
}
algae.rpart
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = algae[i + 11] ~ ., data = algae,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'algae[i + 11]'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please ask programming questions on Stack Overflow — or, in this case, an R forum. The Help Center explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a comma here: `algae[,i + 11]`

Why does this work? See here:

```
> class(algae[1])
[1] "data.frame"
> class(algae[,1])
[1] "factor"
```

`algae[1]` is a list (data frame is special case of a list), while `algae[,1]` is a factor variable.

Often in textbooks (e.g. Hadley Wickham's 'Advanced R') you can find a parallel between a list (or data frame) and a train: if `list` is a train, `list[1]` is its  first car (a very short train but still a train) while `list[,1]` is its  cargo.

Comment: Still, `rpart(a1~.,data=algae[,c(1:11,12)])` and `rpart(algae[,12]~.,data=algae[,c(1:11,12)])` give different results, even when `algae[,12]` and `algae$a1` are clearly identical as shown by `all.equal`.

Comment: I believe you should ask this as separate question. Here, you asked how to solve an error and you got the answer